# Create different objects of model

Tags: c#, .net, object

I have a simple model like this:

```
public class AssignStatisticsModel
{
    public string TasksName { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create four objects into it like:

```
List<AssignStatisticsModel> textModels = new List<AssignStatisticsModel>();
AssignStatisticsModel textmodel = new AssignStatisticsModel();

textmodel.TasksName = "Progress to Back Check";
textModels.Add(textmodel);
textmodel.TasksName = "Back Check to Corrections";
textModels.Add(textmodel);
textmodel.TasksName = "Corrections to Completed";
textModels.Add(textmodel);
textmodel.TasksName = "Progress to Completed";
textModels.Add(textmodel);
```

But for some reason all `TasksNames` called `"Progress to Completed"` instead create one with each `TasksName` I added. Why last  `textModels.Add(textmodel);` replace  four objects with same `TasksName`?

Comment: The answers below are correct.  Your problem is that you are treating your `AssignStatisticsModel` as if it were a "value type" (i.e., a struct) and not a "reference type" (i.e., the class that it is).  You create a single AssignStatisticsModel, set some properties and then add the reference you have to that object to the list.  Then you change the properties and re-add the same reference to the list again.  But, there is only one object and so you get a list containing four references to the same object.  If you had made your type a struct, it would have been copied 4 times each different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new `textmodel` object each time. What you've done is added the same object 4 times to the list:

```
List<AssignStatisticsModel> textModels = new List<AssignStatisticsModel>();

var textmodel = new AssignStatisticsModel { TasksName = "Progress to Back Check" };
textModels.Add(textmodel);
textmodel = new AssignStatisticsModel { TasksName = "Back Check to Corrections" };
textModels.Add(textmodel);
textmodel = new AssignStatisticsModel { TasksName = "Corrections to Completed" };
textModels.Add(textmodel);
textmodel = new AssignStatisticsModel { TasksName = "Progress to Completed" };
textModels.Add(textmodel);
```

Answer (score 7):

You are overwriting the `TasksName` property of the the same instance several times and add the same instance four times to your `List`. [Collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) will fix your issue:

```
var textModels = new List<AssignStatisticsModel>()
{
    new AssignStatisticsModel {TasksName = "Progress to Back Check"},
    new AssignStatisticsModel {TasksName = "Back Check to Corrections"},
    new AssignStatisticsModel {TasksName = "Corrections to Completed"},
    new AssignStatisticsModel {TasksName = "Progress to Completed"},
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating **one instance** (or **object**) of the `AssignStatisticsModel` class, and setting `TasksName` property four times on the **same object**. Passing an object to a method (`Add` method in your example) does not copy the object, instead it passes the *reference* to that exact object to the method. You are actually holding four references to one object, in your list. That's how [*reference types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) work. If `AssignStatisticsModel` was a [*value type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) instead (a `struct` instead of a `class`), then passing your variables to the method would copy their content.

Answer (score 0):

To add to others answers here, you can research the difference between Reference and Value types. Here is a good [link](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

> Reference Type variables are stored in the heap while Value Type variables are stored in the stack. Value Type: A Value Type stores its contents in memory allocated on the stack. When you created a Value Type, a single space in memory is allocated to store the value and that variable directly holds a value.
>   [More Here](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm)

Comment: That's the worse possible explanation about value type and reference type. Sorry, but that difference (which is not accurate and exact at all) is of **no value**. That's an implementation detail, and not the behavioral difference that programmers need to know.